# Evaluate an increasing sum of binomial coefficients: $\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{m+k}{m+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I've been working on a problem and got to a point where I need the closed form of

> $$\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{m+k}{m+1}.$$

I wasn't making any headway so I figured I would see what Wolfram Alpha could do. It gave me this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{m+k}{m+1} = \frac{n((m+2)n+1)}{(m+2) (m+3)}\binom{m+n+1}{ m+1}.$$

That's quite the nasty formula. Can anyone provide some insight or justification for that answer?

Comment: There are a lot of interesting answers for your question. So you should evaluate to accept one of them (unless there are aspects on which you want to discuss. In that case, please tell us.)

Comment: @MarcoCantarini, answer accepted! I can't find much information on that contour integral identity. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is a consequence of the Cauchy's integral formula and the Cauchy's differentiation formula. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the integral representation of the binomial coefficient $$\dbinom{s}{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\left|z\right|=1}\frac{\left(1+z\right)^{s}}{z^{k+1}}dz$$ we have
 $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\dbinom{m+k}{m+1}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\oint_{\left|z\right|=1}\frac{\left(1+z\right)^{m+k}}{z^{m+2}}dz
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\left|z\right|=1}\frac{\left(1+z\right)^{m}}{z^{m+2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\left(1+z\right)^{k}dz
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\left|z\right|=1}\frac{\left(1+z\right)^{m+n+1}}{z^{m+4}}\left(nz-1\right)dz+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\left|z\right|=1}\frac{\left(1+z\right)^{m+1}}{z^{m+4}}dz$$ $$
 =n\dbinom{m+n+1}{m+2}-\dbinom{m+n+1}{m+3}
 $$ which is equivalent to your claim. To see that we have the same result, note that holds $$\dbinom{n}{k}=\frac{n+1-k}{k}\dbinom{n}{k-1}.$$

Comment: +1. Quite neat. I like this method a lot. It will be easier whenever you start with the change ${ m + k \choose m + 1} = {-m - 2 \choose k - 1}\left(-1\right)^{k - 1}$ because it moves the $k$-index to the 'lower floor',

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you. I learned it form your answers :D

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

For  those who  enjoy integrals  here  is another  approach using  the
Egorychev method as  presented in many posts by  @FelixMarin and also by @MarkusScheuer, where we focus on finding an answer  that differs from the approaches that have already been seen.

Suppose we seek to compute

$$S(n,m) = \sum_{k=0}^n k{m+k\choose m+1}.$$

Introduce

$${m+k\choose m+1}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+2}} (1+z)^{m+k} \; dz$$

as well as the Iverson bracket

$$[[0\le k\le n]]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{w^k}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w} \; dw.$$

This yields for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+2}} (1+z)^{m} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} k w^k (1+z)^k
\; dw \; dz.$$

For this to converge we must have $|w(1+z)|<1.$ We get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+2}} (1+z)^{m} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w} 
\frac{w(1+z)}{(1-w(1+z))^2}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+2}} (1+z)^{m+1} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{n}} \frac{1}{1-w} 
\frac{1}{(1-w(1+z))^2}
\; dw \; dz.$$

We evaluate the inner integral using the fact that the residues at the
poles sum to zero. The residue at $w=1$ produces

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+2}} (1+z)^{m+1} 
\frac{1}{(-z)^2} \; dz
= -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+4}} (1+z)^{m+1} \; dz
= 0.$$

For the residue at $w=1/(1+z)$ we re-write the inner integral to get

$$\frac{1}{(1+z)^2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{n}} \frac{1}{1-w} 
\frac{1}{(w-1/(1+z))^2}
\; dw.$$

We thus require
$$\left.\left(\frac{1}{w^{n}} 
\frac{1}{1-w}\right)'\right|_{w=1/(1+z)}
\\ = \left. \left(\frac{-n}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w}
+ \frac{1}{w^n} \frac{1}{(1-w)^2}\right) \right|_{w=1/(1+z)}
\\ = -n (1+z)^{n+1} (1+z)/z + (1+z)^n (1+z)^2/z^2.$$

Substituting this  into the outer  integral and flipping signs  we get
two pieces which are

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+2}} (1+z)^{m-1} n(1+z)^{n+2}/z \; dz
\\ = \frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+3}} (1+z)^{n+m+1} \; dz
= n\times {n+m+1\choose m+2}.$$

The second piece is
$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+2}} (1+z)^{m-1}(1+z)^{n+2}/z^2 \; dz
\\ = - \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+4}} (1+z)^{n+m+1} \; dz
= - {n+m+1\choose m+3}.$$

It follows that our answer is

$$\left(n - \frac{n-1}{m+3}\right) {n+m+1\choose m+2}
= \frac{nm+2n+1}{m+3} {n+m+1\choose m+2}.$$

**Remark.** Being rigorous we also verify that the residue at infinity
in the calculation of the inner integral is zero. We get

$$-\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2}
w^{n} \frac{1}{1-1/w} \frac{1}{(1-(1+z)/w)^2}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
w^{n-2} \frac{w}{w-1} \frac{w^2}{(w-(1+z))^2}
= - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
\frac{w^{n+1}}{w-1} \frac{1}{(w-(1+z))^2}.$$

There is  certainly no pole  at zero here  and the residue is  zero as
claimed (the  term $1+z$ rotates in  a circle around the  point one on
the real axis  and with $\epsilon \lt 1$ it is  never zero). This last
result could  also be obtained  by comparing degrees of  numerator and
denominator.

Comment: Wow, that's intense.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove this by induction.

Here is the induction step:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k  \binom{m+k}{m+1} &= \frac{n((m+2)n+1)}{(m+2)(m+3)}\binom{m+n+1}{m+1} + (n+1)\binom{m+n+1}{m+1} \\
&=\frac{(m+n+2)(m(n+1)+2n+3)}{(m+2)(m+3)} \binom{m+n+1}{m+1} \\
&=\frac{(n+1)(m(n+1)+2n+3)}{(m+2)(m+3)} \cdot \frac{(m+n+2)!}{(m+1)!(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(n+1)((m+2)(n+1)+1)}{(m+2)(m+3)}\cdot \binom{m+n+2}{m+1}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it's not that I couldn't prove it, more that I wanted some insight on why it was true.

Answer (score 2):

The series can also be seen as the following.
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} k \, \binom{m+k}{m+1} &= \frac{1}{m+1} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} k \, \frac{(m+1)_{k}}{k!} \\
&= \frac{1}{m+1} \, \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{(m+1)_{k+2}}{k!} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(m+1)_{k+1}}{k!} \right] \\
&= (m+2) \, \frac{(n-1) \, \Gamma(m+n+2)}{\Gamma(n) \, \Gamma(m+4)} + \frac{ \Gamma(m+n+2)}{\Gamma(n) \, \Gamma(m+3)} \\
&= \frac{(m+n+1)!}{(n-1)! \, (m+3)!} \, (m \, n + 2n + 1) \\
&= \frac{m \, n + 2n + 1}{m+3} \, \binom{m+n+1}{n-1}. 
\end{align}
Rearranging terms yields the form presented in the proposed problem. The notation used in Pochhammer's notation, namely,
\begin{align}
(x)_{k} = \frac{\Gamma(x+k)}{\Gamma(x)}.
\end{align}

Comment: What is that notation- $(m+1)_{k}$?

Comment: @BoRel A note has been added about the notation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different variation of the theme. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ of a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^{n}&k\binom{m+k}{m+1}=\sum_{k=1}^nk[x^{m+1}](1+x)^{m+k}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^{m+1}](1+x)^{m+1}\sum_{k=1}^nk(1+x)^{k-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^{m+1}](1+x)^{m+1}D_x\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(1+x)^{k}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=[x^{m+1}](1+x)^{m+1}D_x\left(\frac{1-(1+x)^{n+1}}{1-(1+x)}-1\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=[x^{m+1}](1+x)^{m+1}\left(\frac{(nx-1)(1+x)^n}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=[x^{m+3}](1+x)^{m+n+1}(nx-1)\tag{7}\\
> &=n[x^{m+2}](1+x)^{m+n+1}-[x^{m+3}](1+x)^{m+n+1}\tag{8}\\
> &=n\binom{m+n+1}{m+2}-\binom{m+n+1}{m+3}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1)
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and split the binomial conveniently
- In (4) we introduce the differential operator $D_x:=\frac{d}{dx}$
- In (5) we use the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*
- In (6) we apply the differential operator $D_x$
- In (7) we do some simplifications and use the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [x^m]x^{-k}A(x)=[x^{m+k}]A(x)
  \end{align*}
- In (8) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule above again
- In (9) we write the expression using binomial coefficients and obtain a result in accordance with the answer of @MarcoCantarini

Comment: Very cool. I have not seen the 'coefficient of' operator before. Where can I read more on it?

Comment: @BoRel: Take a look at section 2.2. of H. Wilf's *[Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)*. You might also want to   have a look at a slightly more *[challenging example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795155/a-strange-combinatorial-identity/1796393#1796393)*.